# Using AudioContext in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to use AudioContext to draw vector sound waves in react native. Used blow code to do so.

```
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();            
const mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
```

But, the audioContext variable is always undenifed. Couldn't get **window.AudioContext** or **window.webkitAudioContext** to work. Both returning **undefined** when used console.log.

It didn't worked because it is react native. Could anyone let me know what is the replacement of **window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext** for react native application.

Thanks in Advance.